# React Native screen stuck at loading screen

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I am creating a simple app. It was working smoothly in emulator but after running on real physical android device it is not working on both emulator and device.

I am using react-native-cli.

After running

```
npm start android
```

I am getting below screen.

[image]

And in device it showing loading please check the below image. I patiently waited but still no luck its on the same loading screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it on Android Studio itself after this command:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: Can you share the project with me? I can try and find the solution for you :) Also, does it work on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

## Restart your phone.

That's all I had to do and the issue fixed itself.